# Making regular expressions look nice in shell scripts

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I often use grep and sed in my bash scripts.
For example, I use a script to remove comments from a template

In this example the comments look like:

```
/*#  my comments contain text and ascii art:
 *#
 *#  [box1] ------> [box2]o
 *#
#*/
```

My sed chain to remove these lines looks like:

```
sed '/^\/\*#/d' | sed '/^\s*\*#/d' | sed '/^\s*#\*\//d'
```

I my scripts, I have to escape chars such as `\` and `/`, which makes the code less readable. Therefore, my question is: **How can I write nice-to-read regular expressions for `sed` in bash scripts?**

One way, I can think of, is by using another separator instead of `/`, as in vim where you can natively use `%s#search/text#replace/text#gc` (using `#` the as separator) and therefore allow `/` as unescaped character. Defining an alternative escape char would also help. I would be interested in how you solve this problem. I am also open for alternative tools in case you think it is only a `sed` problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They help to make regexes a bit cleaner. In addition I also wrote several **sub patterns as variables and functions**, which also makes the code read nicer (IMHO). Here is the current complete [solution to the original problem](http://open-juve.blogspot.de/2012/10/making-regular-expressions-more.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify different separators, [as detailed here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2889/sed-using-colons-as-separators-instead-of-forward-slashes).

Note that Perl allows you to do this too, along with [splitting your regexp across several lines](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347419) for better readability.

Comment: Thx. I like that it is so simple. I thought the solution would be more complex ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to make regex (which a lot of times is a sequence of symbols) nice to read is pretty hard.

However there are a few things you can do:

1. Use `-r` (or `-E` in some systems) so that you don't have to escape regex operators `()`, `{}`, `+`, `?`
2. Use alternative separators, e.g. for `s` command

   ```
   sed 's@regex@replacement@' file
   ```

   For address ranges (you'll need '\')

   ```
   sed '\@pattern@ d' file
   ```
3. Leave spaces between address range and command (like `d` above).
4. Leave comments explaining what the regex matches (you can even include an example).

3 and 4 are more of an indirect approach but they should help.

Anyway what you are doing can be done in a single sed expression:

```
sed '\:^/\*#:,\:^#\*/: d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using alternative separators you may use [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) where appropriate, they invert the escaping rules so you have to write square brackets as "\[\]" to give them the special meaning.

Comment: I think most people would agree that a mass of dancing toothpicks isn't readable at all

Comment: @BrianAgnew - I have removed the arguable part of my answer